# angular 1.6 - peticion post no muestra DIV

Tags: angularjs, rest

estoy presentando un problema a nivel de front al realizar una peticion al un webservice REST, con el metodo POST, al darle clic al boton, la misma se ejecuta con exito, obtengo la  respuesta por parte del api, la misma respuesta debe mostrarme un DIV con el mensaje de "registro exitoso", hice un debug, y en efecto el response viaja al punto en el que deberia de mostrar el mensaje, mas no lo hace, es como que si no se construyera la vista, cabe destacar que si le doy dos click's al boton seguidamente si aparece el mensaje en el front

aca mi codigo en el controlador

```
           insertFactByCategory.insertFacts(data,$rootScope)
           .success(function(success){
               console.log(success);
               vm.validateMessage(success);
           })
           .error(function(error){
              console.log(error);
           });
```

codigo en el servicio factory en angular

```
        function insertFacts(data,$rootScope){
        return $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            url: $rootScope.domainUrlHebdoConf+'/semana/insert/category',
            method: "POST",
            data: data
        });
```

quedo atento a sus comentarios y/o sugerencias

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en el binding de angular.

Al realizar la llamada con Jquery todo funciona correcto, pero angular no dispara el refresco de los datos por que se están realizando "dentro de Jquery".

Cambia la llamada $.ajax por:

```
 return $http.Post($rootScope.domainUrlHebdoConf+'/semana/insert/category', data);
```

($http: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post))

De esta forma cuando se ejecute el success angular actualizara correctamente el div.

Recuerda que debes inyectar el modulo $http en tu factoria para poder utilizarlo.